# To average 2-D numpy.array with numpy.mean or numpy.average

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, average

I am trying to average two-dimensional numpy arrays. So, I used `numpy.mean` but the result is the empty array.

```
import numpy as np
ws1 = np.array(ws1)
ws1_I8 = np.array(ws1_I8) 
ws1_I10 = np.array(ws1_I10)
WSAV = np.mean([ws1,ws1_I8,ws1_I10])
print WSAV
```

I used both `np.mean` and `np.average` but the result is same as the empty array.
The each of `ws1`, `ws1_I8`, `ws1_I10` has the shape of `(18, 75)` and I would like to have the result array of `(18, 75)` shape.

Any idea or help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `ws1`, `ws1_I8` and `ws1_I10` all have shape (18, 75), then `np.mean([ws1, ws1_I8, ws1_I10])` should return mean of all the values in all the arrays. (I'm not sure what you mean by "the result is same as the empty array".)  `np.mean` will convert `[ws1, ws1_I8, ws1_I10]` into a 3-d array with shape (3, 18, 75).  To get `np.mean` to average only along the first axis, use the argument `axis=0`:

```
WSAV = np.mean([ws1, ws1_I8, ws1_I10], axis=0)
```

Or, you could simply write:

```
WSAV = (ws1 + ws1_I8 + ws1_I10) / 3.0
```

Comment: Thank you Warren. This is the answer what I would like to,

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this would do it for you:

```
average_list = [ws1, ws1_I8, ws1_I10]
WSAV = sum(average_list) / len(average_list)
```

Assuming that what you want in your case is `(ws1+ws1_I8+ws1_I10)/3`.

Comment: @CraztCasta Thank you, I couldn't think about that way.